# Регулярное выражение для мак адреса

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, perl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, регулярное выражение, чтобы из

Jun 10 20:33:29 test dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.64 to ce:81:05:3d:b7:d4 via vlan9

оставить только мак адрес

Comment: В чем это все выполняется?

Comment: linux perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/(?:[0-9a-f]{2}\:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Если на sed, то вот так:

```
sed 's/^.*to \([0-9a-f:]*\) via.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

`/((\w{2}\:){5}\w{2})/`

Comment: И что это?

Comment: Да, глупость.
Вот так работает:

my $q = q|Jun 10 20:33:29 test dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.64 to ce:81:05:3d:b7:d4 via vlan9|;
$q =~ m/(([a-f\d]{2}:){5}[a-f\d]{2})/;
print $1, "\n";